# Unix socket doesn't accept connections after daemonization

Tags: unix, rust, daemon, unix-socket

To shorten the time, I am working on a program running as a daemon, and communicating with it by a Unix socket.

It's working perfectly when running it without demonization, But after daemonize, it doesn't accept any connections with the UNIX socket.

I'm using a crate called [daemonize](https://github.com/knsd/daemonize) to demonize the program.

The code:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    Logger::init();
    let args = Args::parse();

    
    if !args.foreground {
        let pid_file = args.pid_file.unwrap_or("/tmp/vnsd.pid".to_owned());


        if Path::new(&pid_file.clone()).exists() {
            std::fs::remove_file(pid_file.clone())
                .map_err(|e| error!("{e}"))
                .unwrap();
        }

        let stdout = File::create("/tmp/vnsd.out").unwrap();
        let stderr = File::create("/tmp/vnsd.err").unwrap();
        let daemonize = Daemonize::new()
            .pid_file(pid_file)
            .chown_pid_file(false)
            .working_directory("/tmp")
            .user(args.user.unwrap_or("nobody".to_owned()).as_str())
            .group(args.group.unwrap_or("nobody".to_owned()).as_str())
            .umask(0o011)
            .stdout(stdout)
            .stderr(stderr)
            .privileged_action(|| println!("Privileged action!"));

        match daemonize.start() {
            Ok(_) => info!("Daemonization starting"),
            Err(e) => {
                error!("Cannot daemonization: {e}");
                std::process::exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    let mut listener = UnixSocket::bind("/tmp/vnsd.sock") 
         .map_err(|e| { 
             error!( 
                 "Cannot bind unix socket server: {}", 
                 e.root_cause().downcast_ref::<std::io::Error>().unwrap() 
             ) 
         }) 
         .unwrap();
    ...

let _: (_, Result<(), anyhow::Error>) = tokio::join!(
        async {
            // run HTTP server (This part is not included)
        },
        async {
            loop {
                listener.handle().await.map_err(|e| error!("{e}")).unwrap();
                match listener.receive().await {
                  ...
            }
       }
}
```

Simple UNIX socket library built on tokio:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct UnixSocket {
    listener: Option<UnixListener>,
    stream: Option<UnixStream>,
}

impl UnixSocket {
    /// bind unix socket
    pub fn bind(path: &str) -> Result<Self> {
        if Path::new(path).exists() {
            warn!("Unix listener address is exist, it will be removed and previous connection will broken.");
           match remove_file(path) {
            Err(e) => return Err(anyhow!(e)),
            Ok(_) => warn!("Unix listener address has been removed")
           };
        }
        match UnixListener::bind(path) {
            Err(e) => Err(anyhow!(e)),
            Ok(listener) => {
                Ok(Self {
                    listener: Some(listener),
                    stream: None,
                })
            }
        }
    }

    /// Connect to unix socket
    pub async fn connect(path: &str) -> Result<Self> {
        Ok(Self {
            listener: None,
            stream: Some(UnixStream::connect(path).await?),
        })
    }

    /// Handling socket connections before receive messages
    pub async fn handle(&mut self) -> Result<&mut Self> {
        println!("handling ...");
 
        // It just await, Doesn't accept or return any errors
        match self.listener.as_ref().unwrap().accept().await { 
            Ok((stream, _)) => {
                println!("accepted!"); 
                self.stream = Some(stream);
                Ok(self)
            }
            Err(err) => Err(anyhow!(err)),
        }
    }

    /// Recieve messages from stream
    pub async fn receive(&self) -> Result<String> {
        println!("check if stream is readable");
        self.stream.as_ref().unwrap().readable().await.unwrap();
        let mut buf = vec![0; 1024];
        println!("buffer has been created");

        match self.stream.as_ref().unwrap().try_read(&mut buf) {
            Ok(n) => {
                buf.truncate(n);
                println!("truncate message");
                Ok(from_utf8(&buf).unwrap().to_owned())
            }
            Err(err) => Err(anyhow!(err)),
        }
    }

    /// Send messages to stream
    pub async fn send(&self, message: &str) -> Result<()> {
        self.stream.as_ref().unwrap().writable().await?;

        if let Err(err) = self.stream.as_ref().unwrap().try_write(message.as_bytes()) {
            return Err(anyhow!(err));
        };
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Executing the command:

```
$ vnsd --user mohamed --group mohamed
```

Comment: You don't provide a reproducible test case which makes it rather difficult to test, but the entire thing seems... odd. What is the point of having a pidfile if you're going to remove it any time the program start? What is the unix socket path, is it also the pidfile?

Comment: And you do know that daemonize will fork internally? And that with modern service managers this is really not considered a good strategy as it means the service manager will lose the process? For ad-hoc daemonification I'd suggest writing a "normal" utility and using `start-stop-daemon` instead.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but a quick note that daemonization is not considered good practice in the modern world -- staying attached to your parent process makes it easier for process supervisors (systemd, launchd, runit, daemontools, etc etc) to monitor your program and store its logs.

Comment: @Masklinn Sorry, I missed the socket path, It's ```/tmp/vnsd.sock```, And deleting the PID file may be a mistake on my part, but it does not affect anything in my problem. I might implement your suggestion about writing a "normal" utility, But I want to know why the UNIX socket doesn't accept any incoming connections? Is there anything effect on it when daemonizing the program?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Maybe I'll do that, But I just want to know the cause of the problem

Comment: So, if I had to guess at the cause -- the file descriptor is probably being opened with the flag (name of which I forget right now) that tells it not to propagate through a `fork()`. Because self-daemonization requires forking... well, there you are. If you want to confirm this guess, that's what syscall-level tracing tools are for (`strace` is the slow standby available everywhere; I personally use `sysdig`; the cool kids use `ebpftrace`).